# I am having an issue with the twig template system

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I have opencart 3 installed on my dev box and have suddenly started getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class Twig_Loader_Filesystem contains 2 abstract methods
>   and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining
>   methods (Twig_LoaderInterface::isFresh,
>   Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface::exists) in
>   /mnt/c/wsl/server/opencart/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php
>   on line 17

I have been working on a custom template and all was going fine until I changed something in the controller of the footer. Changing it back did not resolve the issue. I have also manually cleared the cache in the OC folder and the twig folder. I also did not have the cache setting set to off so I manually made this change in the db as I get the same error trying to get into the admin.

I am at a loss. I would love any help I could get.

Call Stack

> - {main}( )
> - start( )
> - require_once( '/mnt/c/wsl/server/opencart/system/framework.php' )
> - Router->dispatch( )
> - Router->execute( )
> - Action->execute( )
> - ControllerStartupRouter->index( )
> - Action->execute( )
> - ControllerCommonHome->index( )
> - Loader->controller( )
> - Action->execute( )
> - ControllerCommonColumnLeft->index( )
> - Loader->view( )
> - Template->render( )
> - Template\Twig->render( )
> - spl_autoload_call ( )
> - Twig_Autoloader::autoload( )
> - require( '/mnt/c/wsl/server/opencart/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php'
>     )

```
Location
.../index.php:0
.../index.php:19
.../startup.php:104
.../framework.php:165
.../router.php:56
.../router.php:67
.../action.php:79
.../router.php:25
.../action.php:79
.../home.php:12
.../loader.php:48
.../action.php:79
.../column_left.php:72
.../loader.php:125
.../template.php:51
.../twig.php:20
.../twig.php:20
.../Autoloader.php:51


class Twig_Loader_Filesystem implements Twig_LoaderInterface, Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface
{
    /** Identifier of the main namespace. */
    const MAIN_NAMESPACE = '__main__';

    protected $paths = array();
    protected $cache = array();
    protected $errorCache = array();

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param string|array $paths A path or an array of paths where to look for templates
     */
    public function __construct($paths = array())
    {
        if ($paths) {
            $this->setPaths($paths);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the paths to the templates.
     *
     * @param string $namespace A path namespace
     *
     * @return array The array of paths where to look for templates
     */
    public function getPaths($namespace = self::MAIN_NAMESPACE)
    {
        return isset($this->paths[$namespace]) ? $this->paths[$namespace] : array();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the path namespaces.
     *
     * The main namespace is always defined.
     *
     * @return array The array of defined namespaces
     */
    public function getNamespaces()
    {
        return array_keys($this->paths);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the paths where templates are stored.
     *
     * @param string|array $paths     A path or an array of paths where to look for templates
     * @param string       $namespace A path namespace
     */
    public function setPaths($paths, $namespace = self::MAIN_NAMESPACE)
    {
        if (!is_array($paths)) {
            $paths = array($paths);
        }

        $this->paths[$namespace] = array();
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $this->addPath($path, $namespace);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a path where templates are stored.
     *
     * @param string $path      A path where to look for templates
     * @param string $namespace A path name
     *
     * @throws Twig_Error_Loader
     */
    public function addPath($path, $namespace = self::MAIN_NAMESPACE)
    {
        // invalidate the cache
        $this->cache = $this->errorCache = array();

        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            throw new Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('The "%s" directory does not exist.', $path));
        }

        $this->paths[$namespace][] = rtrim($path, '/\\');
    }

    /**
     * Prepends a path where templates are stored.
     *
     * @param string $path      A path where to look for templates
     * @param string $namespace A path name
     *
     * @throws Twig_Error_Loader
     */
    public function prependPath($path, $namespace = self::MAIN_NAMESPACE)
    {
        // invalidate the cache
        $this->cache = $this->errorCache = array();

        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            throw new Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('The "%s" directory does not exist.', $path));
        }

        $path = rtrim($path, '/\\');

        if (!isset($this->paths[$namespace])) {
            $this->paths[$namespace][] = $path;
        } else {
            array_unshift($this->paths[$namespace], $path);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSource($name)
    {
        return file_get_contents($this->findTemplate($name));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCacheKey($name)
    {
        return $this->findTemplate($name);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function exists($name)
    {
        $name = $this->normalizeName($name);

        if (isset($this->cache[$name])) {
            return true;
        }

        try {
            return false !== $this->findTemplate($name, false);
        } catch (Twig_Error_Loader $exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isFresh($name, $time)
    {
        return filemtime($this->findTemplate($name)) <= $time;
    }

    protected function findTemplate($name)
    {
        $throw = func_num_args() > 1 ? func_get_arg(1) : true;
        $name = $this->normalizeName($name);

        if (isset($this->cache[$name])) {
            return $this->cache[$name];
        }

        if (isset($this->errorCache[$name])) {
            if (!$throw) {
                return false;
            }

            throw new Twig_Error_Loader($this->errorCache[$name]);
        }

        $this->validateName($name);

        list($namespace, $shortname) = $this->parseName($name);

        if (!isset($this->paths[$namespace])) {
            $this->errorCache[$name] = sprintf('There are no registered paths for namespace "%s".', $namespace);

            if (!$throw) {
                return false;
            }

            throw new Twig_Error_Loader($this->errorCache[$name]);
        }

        foreach ($this->paths[$namespace] as $path) {
            if (is_file($path.'/'.$shortname)) {
                if (false !== $realpath = realpath($path.'/'.$shortname)) {
                    return $this->cache[$name] = $realpath;
                }

                return $this->cache[$name] = $path.'/'.$shortname;
            }
        }

        $this->errorCache[$name] = sprintf('Unable to find template "%s" (looked into: %s).', $name, implode(', ', $this->paths[$namespace]));

        if (!$throw) {
            return false;
        }

        throw new Twig_Error_Loader($this->errorCache[$name]);
    }

    protected function parseName($name, $default = self::MAIN_NAMESPACE)
    {
        if (isset($name[0]) && '@' == $name[0]) {
            if (false === $pos = strpos($name, '/')) {
                throw new Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Malformed namespaced template name "%s" (expecting "@namespace/template_name").', $name));
            }

            $namespace = substr($name, 1, $pos - 1);
            $shortname = substr($name, $pos + 1);

            return array($namespace, $shortname);
        }

        return array($default, $name);
    }

    protected function normalizeName($name)
    {
        return preg_replace('#/{2,}#', '/', str_replace('\\', '/', (string) $name));
    }

    protected function validateName($name)
    {
        if (false !== strpos($name, "\0")) {
            throw new Twig_Error_Loader('A template name cannot contain NUL bytes.');
        }

        $name = ltrim($name, '/');
        $parts = explode('/', $name);
        $level = 0;
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if ('..' === $part) {
                --$level;
            } elseif ('.' !== $part) {
                ++$level;
            }

            if ($level < 0) {
                throw new Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories (%s).', $name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide any code.

Comment: That is kind of the issue. I have no idea what code would be causing this issue. It's something in the core OpenCart twig template system. I think it relates to the caching system, but not 100% sure on that. I did however post the full call stack of the error.

Comment: Show please Twig_Loader_Filesystem class.

Comment: That file has not be edited, but I have edited the post to include the class in its entirety here.

Comment: And what if you just re upload the OpcenCart framework directory? Overwrite all existing files? Is the error happening in all views/templates or just the onese of recently edited ?

Comment: Is your site running locally? If so, make it a GIT repo and commit the current version of the site. Then overwrite the whole folder with the clean "upload" folder. Then go into a GIT client (Sourcetree for example) and slowly "reject" the changes made by overwriting and see what causes the issue.